# What does the Sitecore.Security.AntiCsrf do and can I disable it on my Content delivery server

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

We are currently having an issue where some ajax requests to async Controller actions are hanging when an exception is thrown inside the action.

When viewed through the currently executing requests you can see the following information

```html
<REQUEST REQUEST.NAME="c500100080026ded" Url="/url" Verb="GET" Stage="SendResponse" Module="SitecoreAntiCSRF" Time="1602531" SITE.ID="2" WP.NAME="14268" APPPOOL.NAME="AppPool" />
```

Is the module needed on Content Delivery servers? Can I completely remove it? What would be the implications if I do so?

The version of sitecore: 8 Update-5

Comment: AntiCSRF...CSRF stand for Cross Site Request Forgery...so AntiCSRF is a module that prevents Cross Site Request Forgery...the implications if you decide to remove the module, mmmm,basically you let your application vulnerable to those kinds of attacks :)

Comment: Well. I don't think it is as black and white as that. We are using mvc controllers and use the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute on all httppost routes. So what does the sitecore module add on top. Is it mainly needed for the admin interface?

Comment: Wondering what your are doing differently, we use quite a bit of web api and I never had to look into this.

Comment: You are correct, but, in order to discuss the grey, we need more information in order to tell you if it is or not safe to remove it!

Comment: It is very weird. Webapi controllers are absolutely fine. Only async mvc actions. To enable async mvc actions we borrowed the idea from kam's blog http://kamsar.net/index.php/2015/05/Enabling-Async-in-Sitecore-Controller-Renderings/

Comment: The other problem is that we only see that issue in one environment which happens to be production. The work around is to stop the action from throwing an exception and then everything works.

Comment: We have also tried adding ignore rules for the specific url but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The module is designed to protect WebForms from CSRF attacks.
By default, it is configured to protect Sitecore interfaces (Sitecore shell) only. However, it supports configuration and can be enabled to protect frontend solutions.

Since Sitecore shell site is disabled on Content Delivery servers the module can safely be disabled or completely removed without any implications.
If you have Sitecore backend enabled on Content Delivery servers the module can be configured to skip processing requests to some specific locations. Just add a  node to Sitecore.AntiCsrf.config file and specify url to filter.

Comment: Thank you! We have got the same response from Sitecore support as well.

Answer (score 2):

The AntiCSRF module validates a cookie value (a Guid) against a form field value.  If your API calls don't contain both of these then the module will raise an error. Interestingly, it doesn't appear to matter what the value actually is.

The module itself injects a `Guid::ToString("D")` but the check doesn't attempt to parse it back into a Guid, or identify if it is the right Guid.  Not sure how good an anti-CSRF check this is, but that aside, the only actual requirement is that the form field name in the request payload must match the `@formFieldName` attribute of the `<AntiCsrf />` element, and the cookie name must match the value of `@cookieName`.

You mentioned that you tried adding ignore rules - that's the appropriate way to disable the functionality for your use case.  I would work on getting this right - it's most likely the rule was not well crafted (or the assumptions about what the rule was testing against were not correct).  Below is a sample of a correctly formatted block.

```xml
<rule name="WFFM">
    <urlPrefix>/sitecore/shell</urlPrefix>
    <ignore wildcard="/sitecore/shell/Applications/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Form Reports*\?*Cart_*_Items_Callback=yes"/>
    <ignore wildcard="/sitecore/shell/~/xaml/Sitecore.Forms.Shell.UI.Dialogs.LookupRecords.aspx*"/>
    <ignore wildcard="/sitecore/shell/~/xaml/Sitecore.Forms.Shell.UI.Dialogs.ListItemsEditor.aspx*"/>
</rule>
```

Note that `@wildcard` rules are executed as a Regex with IgnoreCase.  You can also use `@contains`.  These values, along with `<urlPrefix>` should not include a scheme, and while `<urlPrefix>` is necessary to enable the subsequent matching rules, it is not sufficient on its own.

The other thing you can do is set the `@detectionResult` value to `RaiseException` and set your Sitecore logging to at least `WARN` so that you can see the errors being raised in the Sitecore log - these may help you identify the part of the check that is failing.  The actual logging in the module isn't great so you won't get much benefit from `DEBUG` logging I'm afraid.

Comment: I played around with the ignore rules and made sure the routes are ignored. However the problem still persisted? There must be something else. You are right about logging. It is not great.